# C1815 NPN transistor output voltage doesn't exceed 5 V

Tags: voltage, transistors, npn

The connections are as follows:

- [+5 V from arduino pin] => 680 Ω resistor => C1815 transistor's base pin (3)
- [+14 V from variable power supply] => C1815 transistor's collector pin (2)
- [C1815 transistor's emitter pin (1)] => Load => [Negative from variable power supply].

Oscilloscope probe connected at C1815 transistor's emitter pin (1).

Oscilloscope probe's ground connected at negative from variable power supply.

The arduino PIN in outputing 5v for 1 second, and then 0v for another second in a neverending loop, producing a square-wave pattern on the oscilloscope.

The problem is as follows:
When the variable power supply is turned off, the oscilloscope displays alternating voltage between 0 and 1.5 V.

However, when it's turned on, it displays alternating voltage between 0 and 5 V.

My understanding it that it should alternate between 0 and 14 V, since the collector voltage is 14 V.

Where am I wrong?

Circuit image :
[image]

Comment: Draw a schematic.

Comment: @Hearth There you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 600 Ohm resistor connects to +14 V, and the coil and diode to the collector, and the emitter to GND.

**The negative pole of your 14 V source must also be connected to ground which is negative of the 5 V source.** Without this connection of nothing works really. Maybe you forgot it in the sketch. But even then your circuit can not give more voltage on the emitter a (base voltage -
base drop).

[image: Something like this]

Comment: So if i understand correctly, per your schematic, ( -14 V & -5 V & emitter) should all share a common ground ?

Comment: Connecting both ground worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

With the load between the transistor emitter and Ground/negative, you have an emitter follower.  The emitter voltage will be about 0.7 volts below the base voltage.

I assume the Arduino is applying a pulsing voltage to the transistor base.

Comment: mmm Interessting , never tought of that. Considering the schematic above, any advice on what i should change to break the emmitter follower pattern ? Its a new concept to me, and im not sure why it's hapenning

Comment: @Charles-UgoBrouillard Use the transistor as a low-side switch, with the load between +14 V and the collector.

Comment: @Hearth Perfect, and just to be sure , also connect the emitter of the transistor to the negative side of the 14 V power supply ?

Comment: Read on the low-side switch, much needed insight in this situation. Thanks @Hearth